# Popup leaflet map

Tags: leaflet

I want to be able to open and close a map marker popup without having to click the marker to do this action.

I would like to know if there is a way to make a list using primevue's "listbox" component, and by selecting the options in the list open the different popups of my markers in a leaflet map.